# Does it make sense to build api and web in one app?

Tags: laravel

My employer recently learned of Laravel, and has asked us to migrate much of our development to it. None of us have issues with this, as we’ve all played around with it.

We have two main in-house products: an api, and a web app which calls said api. The discussion we’re currently having, is does it make sense to put both products into the same Laravel application?

I do apologize if this is the wrong place to ask.

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Its depends on how closely coupled your app and api are.

If there is tight coupling, you always want to deploy the app and api together. a new version of either requires an update of the other

If there is loose coupling, then you wont want to redeploy the api every time you change the logo on the app for example. Do you need to run two versions of the api at the same time? Is there another app that uses the same API so that the API has more load and needs more boxes than the app? etc etc

Even if you have zero downtime deployments you will want to keep your deployments and versioning simple. Each method offers a different sort of simplicity.